# Title: Error creating schedule for each employee in Neo4j

Tags: database, database-design, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to create a schedule for each employee the nodes of which have the following pattern in my Neo4j database:

```
CREATE (:Employee {employee_id: randomUUID(), name: 'John Doe', sex: 'Male', salary: 25000000, age: 35, job_title: 'Manager', date_of_joining: '2018-01-01', email_address: 'johndoe@example.com', department: 'Sales'})
```

The database already contains information about employees, including their working shifts.
I want to create a schedule for each employee that shows their actual start and end times for each day of the week.

```
MATCH (e:Employee)
    FOREACH (day IN ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'] |
        CREATE (e)-[:HAS_SCHEDULE]->(:Schedule {day: day})
    )
    WITH ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening'] AS shifts, e
    UNWIND range(1, 7) AS day_number
    WITH shifts, e, day_number
    ORDER BY rand()
    WITH shifts[0] AS shift1, shifts[1] AS shift2, shifts[2] AS shift3, e, day_number
    CREATE (e)-[:WORKS_SHIFT]->(:WorkShift {name: shift1, start_time: '09:00', end_time: '15:00'})-[:ON_DAY]->(:Day {day_number: day_number})
    CREATE (e)-[:WORKS_SHIFT]->(:WorkShift {name: shift2, start_time: '15:00', end_time: '21:00'})-[:ON_DAY]->(:Day {day_number: day_number})
    CREATE (e)-[:WORKS_SHIFT]->(:WorkShift {name: shift3, start_time: '21:00', end_time: '03:00'})-[:ON_DAY]->(:Day {day_number: day_number});
```

That code worked and created the working shifts for each employee. However, when I tried to create a schedule for each employee using the following code:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)
    FOREACH (year IN range(2021, 2023) |
        FOREACH (month IN range(1, 12) |
            FOREACH (week IN range(1, ceil(toFloat(size([day IN range(1, 31) WHERE date({year: year, month: month, day: day}).month = month])) / 7))) |
                FOREACH (day IN range(1, size([d IN range(1, 31) WHERE date({year: year, month: month, day: d}).month = month]))) |
                    CREATE (e)-[:HAS_SCHEDULE]->(:Schedule {year: year, month: month, week: week, day: day})
                )
            )
        );
```

I encountered this error message:

```
(line 4, column 145 (offset: 237))
"        FOREACH (week IN range(1, ceil(toFloat(size([day IN range(1, 31)
WHERE date({year: year, month: month, day: day}).month = month])) / 7))) |"
                                                                       ^
```

What is this issue?

Comment: Each foreach closing parenthesis is below it. So there are too many closing parentheses on that line. (When a caret points at a closing parenthesis, start counting.) PS Debug questions require a [mre]. That's minimal code that is code that works plus minimal code giving the error. That means chopping code until the error goes away then adding back for the error. (Debug fundamental.) (Don't just dump wrong code into a question.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `FOREACH` loop before the `|` operator, also you need to wrap `ceil` with `toInteger`, since you are using it in a `range` function. This will work:

```
MATCH (e:Employee)
FOREACH (year IN range(2021, 2023) |
    FOREACH (month IN range(1, 12) |
        FOREACH (week IN range(1, toInteger(ceil(toFloat(size([day IN range(1, 31) WHERE date({year: year, month: month, day: day}).month = month])) / 7))) |
            FOREACH (day IN range(1, size([d IN range(1, 31) WHERE date({year: year, month: month, day: d}).month = month])) |
                CREATE (e)-[:HAS_SCHEDULE]->(:Schedule {year: year, month: month, week: week, day: day})
            )
        )
    )
);
```